# Received HTTP code 501 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, proxy, bitbucket, git-bash, git-clone

Whenever I try to clone a repository from bitbucket, it gives me following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://user_name@bitbucket.org/user_name/repo_name.git/': Received HTTP code 501 from proxy after CONNECT

Can't understand what is the problem. I am copying `git clone` command from bitbucket repository web. I have also set git `http.proxy` but it didn't work.

Let me know if more information is required.

Thanks

Comment: I got HTTP 500 from proxy after CONNECT. Any way to solve this.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, your proxy doesn't support [HTTP CONNECT tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_tunneling), that's why it responds with `HTTP 501 (Not implemented)` code:

> #### HTTP CONNECT tunneling
>
> A variation of HTTP tunneling when behind an HTTP Proxy Server is to
>   use the "CONNECT" HTTP method.
>
> In this mechanism, the client asks an HTTP Proxy server to forward the
>   TCP connecting to the desired destination. The server then proceeds to
>   make the connection on behalf of the client. Once the connection has
>   been established by the server, the Proxy server continues to proxy
>   the TCP stream to and from the client. Note that only the initial
>   connection request is HTTP - after that, the server simply proxies the
>   established TCP connection.
>
> This mechanism is how a client behind an HTTP proxy can access
>   websites using SSL (i.e. HTTPS).
>
> **Not all HTTP Proxy Servers support this feature, and even those that
>   do, may limit the behaviour** (for example only allowing connections to
>   the default HTTPS port 443, or blocking traffic which doesn't appear
>   to be SSL).

Comment: Hmm, should I ask my Network Administrator to allow proxy work without SSL?

Comment: That won't work, since Bitbucket enforces SSL on everything.

Comment: HTTP 500 after CONNECT for me. What should be done to solve this ?